# Integrate with LDAP in Azure

Tags: azure, ldap, appfabric

Our application store some user information(username, password) in LDAP, and because we cannot change the authenticate code, so we would like to setup a LDAP server in Azure, but I do not see Azure provide such service.

is it possible?

Curently, we have LDAP, DataBase, Application(java,tomcat). DataBase is used to store some business information, LDAP is used to store user credentials.

If user want to use our service, he should sign up, then we will store his credentials to LDAP and when he login, we will compare the credential.

Answer (score 2):

LDAP works within the bounds of a domain, but your browser will not present your credentials to sites out on the internet.

I have two suggestions, I haven't tested either of them.

**Option 1:**

Use [Windows Azure Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started/) to add the Azure boxes to your own domain, thus allowing users within the domain to authenticate.

**Option 2:**

Install [AD FS 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services) on your companie's intranet or DMZ, and then add it as an identity provider in the Access Control Service. You then add the Access Control Service as an identity provider in your application. When a user attempts to use your application, they will be redirected to the AD FS server (via the ACS) to authenticate with their local credentials.

Comment: My answer awas about to be option 2.

Comment: I would also suggest option 2, but it really depends on what you need your application to do. Regardless, Windows Azure Connect is still in CTP [http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/virtual-network] so a production ready solution would be ADFS+ACS.

Comment: Option 2 may not very suitable for us. we have our LDAP, DataBase, Application(java,tomcat) now, if we move our service to azure, we would like all of them hosted on azure;and seems it requires to change the existing code.
Our LDAP server is just used to store user credentials, when user sign up, we save it to LDAP, when user login, we compare the password. Normally, in a azure application, how they implement it?